# Any way to force on/off the fan on an nVidia Quadro FX 3500?

Tags: fan, nvidia-quadro

I have an nVidia Quadro FX 3500. It's got a fan - not too loud, but the thing is constantly turning on and off. Two seconds on, one off, then one on, then three off, etc. The intermittent pattern is driving me and my coworkers crazy.

Aside from swapping in a new card (which I'm really considering) is there anything else I can do? I just want the stupid fan to stay on all the time. It's the pattern that is annoying.

When I was Googling for an answer, I saw a lot of apps to control fan speed on CPU's and cases but nothing for an nVidia GPU fan. Does anyone have any suggestions here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [RivaTuner](http://www.guru3d.com/rivatuner/) since yours is an Nvidia card.

[image]

Comment: Woops, just saw yours is actually a Quadro. Not too sure if RivaTuner works then.

Comment: Just checked - it should work. Certain options might not be available though, but the fan control should be usable.

Comment: Yup it works with the Quadro, though the sliders seem to only control the fan velocity and not how when it's activated. That's ok though, pulling it down to the minimum speed helps a lot with the noise problem (I have a really well ventilated case on here). Thanks!

Comment: @Scott Bilas: Thanks for the update too! At least we now know how well RivaTuner works with Quadro cards. Glad it helped you, have a great day! ;)

Comment: RivaTuner hasn't been updated since 2009

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check out RivaTuner. Here's an article that explains fan speed control using RivaTuner:
http://www.guru3d.com/article/rivatuner-20-fan-speed--overclock-guide/